# how to write to query to fetch for particular date and also range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

audit_modifier is VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) and audit_modifier values are stored in this format[2018-01-18T17:19:47.285Z].

then how to write to query to fetch for particular date and also range of dates.

SELECT * FROM TABLE where audit_modifier =  '2018-01-18';

getting below error message.

select *
from TABLE 
WHERE trunc(audit_modifier) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2018-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
                             TO_DATE('2018-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 29

Comment: If you can't figure it out using the duplicate link, then drop a note here and someone can reopen the question for you.

Comment: written the query above using the answer link posted above but getting error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that you are storing timestamp information as text in the following format:

```
2018-01-18T03:22:48.317Z
```

You should be storing your date information in a date column, but we can workaround this.  We can convert this string to a timestamp using `TO_TIMESTAMP`, then truncate it to a date:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-18T03:22:48.317Z',
                         'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFFZ')) =
    TO_DATE('2018-01-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: audit_modifier is varchar2 column.why no records are coming when we execute for particular date?.SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE  audit_modifier = '2018-01-18';;values exists like this in the table 2018-01-18T03:22:48.317Z
2018-01-18T06:22:34.949Z

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SUBSTR(audit_modifier, 1, 10) = '2018-01-18'` ... but _don't_ store your dates as text.

Comment: this is old table so we cannot change it.